# React ref & Formik innerRef - current.values doesn't get updated

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-ref

I'm trying to use Formik in combination with React's `useRef` hook to create a reference to my form, which I can then access outside of that form. However, no matter what I do, the values in the ref are never updated like I expect them to.

I've created a small example demonstrating the problem.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik } from "formik";

const App = () => {
  const formRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("formRef changed", formRef.current);
  }, [formRef]);

  const email = useMemo(() => {
    if (formRef.current) {
      const email = formRef.current.values;
      return email;
    }

    return "<none>";
  }, [formRef.current?.values]); //This dependency array was a test, I tried formRef and formRef.current separately aswell.

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Formik
        innerRef={(f) => (formRef.current = f)}
        initialValues={{ email: "asdf@test.com" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        {(props) => {
          const {
            values,
            isSubmitting,
            handleChange,
            handleReset,
            handleSubmit
          } = props;
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="email" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                id="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                type="text"
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <button type="button" className="outline" onClick={handleReset}>
                Reset
              </button>
              <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
      <span>Entered e-mail: {email}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work with Stack Snippets, so I made a codesandbox instead:
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-0osy6?file=/index.js

I originally wanted to do it this way because I need this value somewhere completely unrelated to the form. I considered just using a state variable but this felt like unnecessarily duplicating state, but I might be wrong.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `const formRef = useRef();` 
use : `const [values, setValues] = useState({});`

in Formik replace `innerRef={(f) => (formRef.current = f)}`
with: 
 `innerRef={(formikActions) => (formikActions? setValues(formikActions.values) : setValues({})}`

now u can update the useEffect to listen to the values state , and so the changes will always be listened to .

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("values changed", values);
  }, [values]);
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, probably because you shouldn't pass a non useRef value to innerRef. However, this solution fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

useRef can't notify, You can't rerender  react component.
For rerender the page u neeed to use useState for updating your component when the value update .

Answer (score 0):

The react `useRef` can not be updated with state change. There's no way to update if you need the values you will have to try another approach, or use the Formik `useField` to get value of the field that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You totally can access the values of Formik from else where by using the Ref. Here when I add a callback for submit button, you can see that the values got updated.

```
// Helper styles for demo
import "./helper.css";

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik } from "formik";

const App = () => {
  const formRef = useRef();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("formRef changed", formRef.current);
  }, [formRef]);

  const submitForm = () => {
    setEmail(formRef.current.values.email);
  };

  const resetForm = () => {
    formRef.current.resetForm();
  };

  // const email = useMemo(() => {
  //   if (formRef.current) {
  //     const email = formRef.current.values;
  //     return email;
  //   }

  //   return "<none>";
  // }, [formRef.current?.values]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize
        innerRef={(f) => (formRef.current = f)}
        initialValues={{ email: "asdf@test.com" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        {(props) => {
          const {
            values,
            isSubmitting,
            handleChange,
            handleReset,
            handleSubmit
          } = props;
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="email" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                id="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                type="text"
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <button type="button" className="outline" onClick={resetForm}>
                Reset
              </button>
              <button disabled={isSubmitting} onClick={submitForm}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
      <span>Entered e-mail: {email}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

working code in Sandbox here
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-7nxcni?file=/index.js

Additionally, you can also have the ref in parent component and pass it to child component. Check this sandbox out, https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-pfri64?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

A while back there was an open PR on the formik issues that would have solved this issue but it seems that it was left for dead and untouched for over a year now.

If you are using the `Formik` component and need to specifically track changes  to any formik values... to essentially trigger a `useEffect` here is my solution that worked well for my team.

To give some context we had a lot of forms using the same approach as the one in your example. We needed to access `formik.dirty` and `formik.values` to track user interaction and dispatch some google analytics tracking events.

For my solution I created a function component with no markup output. It needs to be mounted inside the `Formik` wrapper and using the `useFormikContext` hook it gets access to all the values and can track any changes to them in a `useEffect`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';

const FormikChangeHandler = () => {
  const { dirty, values } = useFormikContext();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    /* Add your custom logic here */
    console.log('dirty', dirty);
    console.log('values', values);
  }, [dirty, values]);
};

export default FormikChangeHandler;
```

Then you would simple import this component where your `Formk` wrapper is and mount it like this

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import FormikChangeHandler from "./FormikChangeHandler";

const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize
        innerRef={(f) => (formRef.current = f)}
        initialValues={{ email: "asdf@test.com" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        {(props) => {
          const {
            values,
            isSubmitting,
            handleChange,
            handleReset,
            handleSubmit
          } = props;
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <FormikChangeHandler />
              <label htmlFor="email" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                id="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                type="text"
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <button type="button" className="outline" onClick={resetForm}>
                Reset
              </button>
              <button disabled={isSubmitting} onClick={submitForm}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
      <span>Entered e-mail: {email}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

You can then build any logic inside the `FormikChangeHandler` component to suit your needs.

I hope this offers a viable solution.